StatusPages won't use route installed ContentNegotiation plugin
I'm trying to add a GraphQL route.
This route has a custom ContentNegotiation plugin, which forced me to move the installation of the global ContentNegotiation plugin from Application to root Route (Routing).
So far, so good, yet I'm using StatusPages plugin to serialize Exceptions into a custom json response.
Since I moved the installation of the ContentNegotiation plugin into the root route (Routing), Ktor is unable to correctly serialize my error response, and instead responds Error Code 406, and an empty body.
StatusPages, however, is not a RouteScopedPlugin, so it seems content negotiation capabilities are lost in StatusPages

What prevents you from installing the StatusPages plugin on the application level?

It is installed on the application level, it cannot even be installed on Route level

@AlekseiTirman the one plugin I cannot move to application level is the ContentNegotiation plugin

Why do you need this if you can have the ContentNegotiation plugin installed on the routing level and the StatusPages plugin on the application level?

@AlekseiTirman, that's exactly my setup. StatusPages responses cannot serialize Json correctly.

I've tested a similar setup, and it works with the StatusPages installed on the application level.
